# Need to keep collapsible 1 open when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used the following example from W3schools to create a collapsible menu : 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol
I just need to make a provision that the first collapsible is open when the page is first loaded. How should I go about doing this ?

HTML :

```
        <div class="singleFeature" ng-repeat="feature in myJson.bottomFeatures">
            <button class="collapsible" ng-click="collapse($index);" ng-class = "{'active':$index == featureSelectedPos}">{{feature.title}}</button>
            <div class="content" id="{{$index}}">
                <div ng-repeat="subfeat in feature.subfeatures">
                        <div class="subfeature-title">{{subfeat.title}}</div>
                        <div class="subfeature-paragraph">{{subfeat.paragraph}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795'; 
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.subfeature-title
{
  font-size: 14px;
}

.subfeature-paragraph
{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; 
}
```

Javascript

```
  $scope.collapse = function(id)
  {
    if($scope.featureSelectedPos==id)//Closing an open div
    {
      $scope.featureSelectedPos = null;
      document.getElementById(id).style.maxHeight = null;   
    }
    else
    {
      if($scope.featureSelectedPos != null){
          document.getElementById($scope.featureSelectedPos).style.maxHeight = null;     
      }
      document.getElementById(id).style.maxHeight = document.getElementById(id).scrollHeight + "px";
      $scope.featureSelectedPos = id;
    }

  }
```

Comment: *"How should I go about doing this ? "* Step 1: show us what **your** code looks like

Comment: @Thomas edited the original post to show my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the click event on first button at the end of your code:

```
document.querySelector('.collapsible').click();
```

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
document.querySelector('.collapsible').click();
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is when I load the page I can see the animation of it opening.

Comment: @ArikBadami, as you are calculating the max-height in JavaScript, I believe there is no simple solution to overcome that:)